# I can't install NodeJS 8 because when it tries to update chrome-gnome-shell doesn't have an artful release

Tags: command-line, gnome, nodejs

Whenever i try to use the command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -` it stops when it tries to do an update because chrome-gnome-shell (http://ppa.launchpad.net/ne0sight/chrome-gnome-shell/ubuntu) doesn't have an artful release. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

If you search for Software & Updates , go to the Other Software tab, you can locate the chrome-gnome-shell PPA and untick it, or just remove it completely.

[image]